# class 'Pusher\Pusher' not found required in laravel package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, package, pusher

I'm creating my own Laravel package and I required Pusher server in my package, in my composer.json there is a pusher required and I also checked it in vendor folder also exist ... and when I'm trying to use it in my package controller like use `Pusher\Pusher`;
it says that class `'Pusher\Pusher'` not found!!!

my composer.json :

```
...
"require": {
    ...
    "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^3.4@dev"
},
...
```

in my controller I added use Pusher\Pusher; and the use is like that :

```
public function pusher()
{
    $pusher = new Pusher(
        env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        [
            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
            'encrypted' => true
        ]
    );
}
```

Does anyone have a solution??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you put your composer.json codes here?

Comment: please add all relevant code to the question (composer.json and calling code)

Comment: What is your namespace in Pusher class?

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/IRiz1fz) this is my composer.json

Comment: Did you run `composer update` ?

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image on an external site. Edit your question and paste the code there. Thx

Comment: @MohammadrezaYektamaram yes but nothing

Comment: Namespace of your file is very important, please put here your php file to help you.

Comment: @MohammadrezaYektamaram the namespace of the package?

Comment: Yes, Of course the package

Comment: the namespace of my package is Munafio and my controller namespace is (Munafio\Http\Controllers)

Comment: try to run this code in your cmd       **composer update**

Comment: nothing to be updated @PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got nothing after a long ride of searching in google and asking the developer...

But I finally SOLVED it :)

If you are developing your own package and trying to require a dependency inside the package .. and got the same error!! all you need to do is to require it at the beginning of creating the composer.json file for your package, or put your dependencies in the require of your composer.json file and remove your package from laravel app and then re-install it.

you may not need to do that, all you need is to require the dependency and everything gonna work successfully.